# Mockito: Why does this verify with ArgumentCaptor not match?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am working on some tests for a project here at my company. I used `Mockito.verify(...)` in combination with some `ArgumentCaptor` quite a bit but know I am a bit puzzeled, because in my case the following test code does not work out as expected:

```
@Mock BuildHandler buildHandler;
...
ArgumentCaptor<Build> savedBuildCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Build.class);
verify(buildHandler, times(1)).save(savedBuildCaptor.capture());
...
```

I expected the `savedBuildCaptor` to catch me any `Build` object that is passed to the `buildHandler.save(Build b)` method. In fact during the execution I end up with this test failure from Mockito:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted: buildHandler.save(null);
Actual invocation has different arguments: buildHandler.save(1234);
```

Can anyone point me to where I (might have) screwed up?

If additional code/info is required I'll post it.

Comment: Can you explain how this is a duplicate? AFAIK do not use the `ArgumentCaptor` for stubbing. Actually I do exactly the same stuff that is written in the answer of that post.

Comment: What's the signature of the `save(...)` method?

Comment: It's an interface method defined as `public void save(Build build) throws DatabaseException;`

Comment: If you take the `times(1)` argument out, does it work?

Comment: Indeed it does. Which I think is strange but anyway. I did not try this. If you post it as answer I'd mark it as solved!

Comment: This is, as you say, very strange. What version of Mockito are you using? I did some tests with the latest (`1.10.19`) and `times(1)` didn't matter...

Comment: I am using `1.10.19` as well. The strange thing is that it is working with other test cases, but this one is failing when I put hte `times(1)` in place. I think I'll file a bug with `Mockito` maybe they can figure something out.